# How can I get a value out of inquirer.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, inquirerjs

I am building a small CLI app using javascript, yargs, inquirer, and superagent. In inquirer I am asking the user to enter a choice of miles to be used in my app. I want to use that value somewhere else in my app but I can't seem to able to get the value returned. Below is my latest attempt. Any help into getting this value returned from `selectRange` would be highly appreciated.

```js
const selectRange = (result) => {
    return inquirer.prompt([{
        type: 'checkbox',
        message: 'Select the range in miles to search',
        name: 'miles',
        choices: ['50', '100','150', '200', '250'] ,
        validate: (result) => {
            if (result.length > 1) {

                return 'Error: You must select 1 choice     only'

            } else {
                return true
            }
        },
        filter: input => {
            return input

        }

    }]).then(input => {
        return input
    })
}



const surroundingCitiesWeather = (location) => {

    const range = selectRange()

    console.log(`Range selected is ${range}`)
}
```

[Here is a pic of my output, mind the last line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW9lV.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your function is returning a Promise, so you'd need to use it:

```
const surroundingCitiesWeather = (location) => {
    selectRange().then(range => {
        console.log(`Range selected is ${range}`)
    })
}
```

If you use a recent version of node, you can make a bit clearer using async/await:

```
const surroundingCitiesWeather = async (location) => {
    const { range } = await selectRange()
    console.log(`Range selected is ${range}`)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`inquirer.prompt` returns a Promise, so in your case you just need to add `async/await` to your function, and then just return `answer.range` at the end.

Also, I don't think you need the `result` function parameter. So the following should work:

```js
const selectRange = async () => {
  return await inquirer.prompt([
    {
      type: "checkbox",
      message: "Select the range in miles to search",
      name: "miles",
      choices: ["50", "100", "150", "200", "250"],
      validate: (result) => {
        if (result.length > 1) {
          return "Error: You must select 1 choice     only";
        }
        return true;
      },
      filter: (input) => input,
    },
  ]).then((answer) => answer.range);
};
```

Then the other block should also await for the promise to be resolved:

```js
const surroundingCitiesWeather = async(location) => {

    const range = await selectRange()

    console.log(`Range selected is ${range}`)
}
```

Comment: Your function still returns a Promise, so it would not fix the problem

Comment: good point. added a snippet to show how to consume it.